# validation of textbox after using calendar

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, regex

How can I disable the textbox after selecting a value from the calendar?

```
    <s:textfield theme="simple" name="" id="startDate" style="width:80px" cssClass="tcal"/>
```

Note: "tcal" is the class defined in .css file and I am using one .js file for functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `onfocus` Event.On selecting value from calendar focus returns to textbox,that time you check if textbox has value and value is of dateType(in Correct Format)then Disable it.

```
<s:textfield theme="simple" name="" 
 id="startDate" style="width:80px"
cssClass="tcal" onfocus="Disable()"/>
```

your JS will be like :-

```
 function Disable()
    {
    var obj=document.getElementById('startDate');
    //Check if it has value, then it is in correct format:-
    if(obj.value && inCorrectFormat)
    obj.disable=true;
    }
```

Comment: I am having my calender inside the textbox. So on disabling the textbox the calender is also getting disabled. Any suggestions how to solve this issue?